# Why does the animation act like this after exporting from Blender to Unity (.fbx)

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, fbx

Hi this is a frame in my animation in blender
[blender's animation frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVkkw.png)

but when I export it in .fbx it looks like this in Unity

[Unity's animation frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x3Mp.png)

Why does this happen? Do I mess up with blender's export parameters?

EDIT:
I am new to Blender and Unity so please don't be rude :)
These are the files:
[file .blend and .fbx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IvQzepMIpVfjvIWJ3YEOrq1j6CTfnm9Y/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Difficult to say. With only the screenshots it's hard to judge what may cause the issue. We definitely need more information. Can you upload the `.blend` file, the `.fbx` generated and maybe a sekeleton Unity project for attempts of recreation?

Comment: Ok, edited. In unity I just drag and drop the fbx inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change [quality setting](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SkinnedMeshRenderer.html) in your skinned mesh renderer
or/and [Blend Weights](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-QualitySettings.html#BlendWeights) in Project settings

Unity for performance reasons keep amount of bones affecting vertices as low as possible. Default values are AFAIR 1. The best scenario is that every vertex is affected by only one bone, and you should try achieve this in blender. But If you need more bones per vertex you should increase Unity settings accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much. It solves my problem